# Approach for hyperparameter tuning when same parameters have varying accuracy (due to non deterministic behavior) - LSTM training Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, random-seed

I am using tf.truncated_normal_initializer to initialize the weights and biases:

```
with tf.variable_scope('params'):
    weights = tf.get_variable(name="weights1",shape = [2*rnn_size, n_classes],initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(seed=seed))
    biases = tf.get_variable(name="biases1",shape = [n_classes],initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(seed=seed))
```

and to keep them the same for different runs for reproducibility, I set seed at op level. Also I set the same seed inside the same graph using

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
```

and later:

```
tf.set_random_seed(seed)
```

Apart from this I also set numpy and random seed to same value as above seeds (tfseed has same value as seed).

```
np.random.seed(tfseed)
random.seed(tfseed)
```

On training and printing the value for Run 1 , Run 2 and Run 3 at epoch 0 and comparing them , I noticed slight changes in the weights.

[Epoch 0 weights run 0 vs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT7GG.png)

[Epoch 0 run 1 vs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5J755.png)

by epoch 94 the changes become more visible:

[Epoch 94 run 0 vs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBw4d.png)

[Epoch 94 run 1 vs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0I6Eu.png)

At much higher epochs 1000+ the weights may become much more different resulting in different accuracies. I am attempting to have reproducibility to try out different hyperparameters.

What is the reason behind those small differences in the weights/biases for different runs even though the seed is the same and how do we avoid it?

And is there a way to avoid different weights for different runs for complete reproducibility at very high epochs?

**UPDATE EDIT -** 
The weights printed at epoch 0 were printed **after** epoch 0 , I misunderstood that  these weights are the initial weights. After I noticed this and printed weights just before the epoch computation. I can see that the initial weights are the same. So the seed is working as intended.

[Before Epoch 0 - Run 0 weights vs Run 1 weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYoq2.png)

[Before Epoch 0 - Run 1 weights vs Run 2 weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn3JT.png)

From the comment and other resources, it seems that the way tensorflow work on GPU/CPU (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3103) , tf.reduce_mean and tf.reduce_sum are non-deterministic, which may explain why the weights keep changing at different epoch for different runs, leading to different accuracy at high epoch (4 to 7% difference at 1000 epoch for 10 runs for me on training LSTM).

How is the hyper parameter tuning usually done when there is variation in accuracy using same parameters (due to non deterministic behavior)? How is It decided that increase in accuracy is actually due to the hyper parameter change?

Comment: Are you using a GPU? GPU operations are basically nondeterministic, and based on this issue it looks like some tf use of GPU may also still be nondeterministic: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2732

Comment: Yes , I am using GPU. And I understand from the link you shared that tensorflow using GPU will introduce non deterministic behavior. Are there any other libraries apart from tensorflow which avoid non deterministic behavior for RNN training?
 How do people usually do hyper parameter tuning when the accuracy varies 4-7 %  with same parameters (due to non deterministic behavior)?

Comment: Can you get away with CPU training? That would be deterministic. I don't know how people solve that issue on a GPU. As practical advice, if you see that much variance in accuracy, then perhaps hyperparam tuning at this point is just overfitting.

Comment: Well using 2 GPU (NVIDIA® Tesla P100), 1 run takes 3 hours. I do not think using CPU is an option. Maybe the variation in accuracy is due to different local minimas? I do not understand, why  would it be overfitting?

Comment: I don't have enough information to really know if it is overfitting or not. Overfitting is a danger whenever you spend a lot of time improving some metric without clear evidence that the metric is definitely getting better. If you see up to 7% variance in accuracy, that sounds like it would be easy to try to optimize things without clear evidence that the metric is definitely getting better.